# R summarise with multiple evalution metric functions that use actual and predicted from a data frame

Tags: r

I want to calculate multiple model evaluation metrics by groups for a data set. Each metric requires the input of actual (observed) and predicted values.  These are columns in my data frame. My groups are represented by the variables iTime and an_id.

I can do the necessary calculations with summarise and much redundant typing, but there must be a purrr way to do this. I am trying to master purrr.  I have tried `invoke_map` and `pmap` but could not figure out how to refer to the columns "actual" and "predicted" in my data frame.

A short example - there are more metrics needed:

```
library(Metrics)    
  df <- data.frame(an_id = c('G','J','J', 'J', 'G','G','J','G'),    
                  iTime = c(1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2), 
                 actual = c(1.28, 2.72,.664,.927,.711,1.16,.727,.834),    
                 predicted = c(1.14,1.61,.475,.737,.715,1.15,.725,.90))



  dataMetrics <- df %>% 
                   group_by(an_id, iTime)  %>% 
                    summarise(vmae = mae(actual, predicted), 
                             rae = rae(actual, predicted), 
                              vrmse = rmse(actual, predicted))
> dataMetrics
 A tibble: 4 x 5
  an_id iTime  vmae  rae  vrmse   
 <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 G         1 0.072 0.253 0.0990    
2 G         2 0.038 0.233 0.0472    
3 J         1 0.556 0.558 0.785     
4 J         2 0.190 1.44  0.190
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. Where do `mae`, `mase` and `rmse` come from? Are they custom functions? Generally it seems `purrr::invoke_map` may be what you're looking for, but it's difficult to give specific help without reproducible example.

Comment: Also please add your expected output for the sample data you give. Grouping by `an_id` and `iTime` will result in some groups having only one observation, which makes calculating summary stats not very meaningful. But perhaps this is because of your simplified sample data? Either way, please give expected output.

Comment: Some more information:  I am calculating multiple model evaluation metrics from the package Metrics. "actual" is a vector of observed values and "predicted" is a vector of predicted values from my models. For example, mae is mean absolute error: absolute value of (predicted - actual).

Comment: I did not include the entire data set.  My question is generalizes to how to refer to two columns in a data frame when summarizing with multiple functions that use those same two columns.  My specific case with multiple functions using actual and predicted values as the columns is a common case.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments as comments are transient! Always edit your original post to include critical details. I've posted a solution below that you should be able to adjust to whatever functions you're using to calculate summary stats. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks for you comments on how to properly post.

Comment: Great, your post is much better now! Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to reproduce your expected output, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't know where `mae`, `mase` and `rmse` come from, which regrettably makes your example not reproducible. It's important to *always* explicitly state which packages you're using.**

`invoke_map` is the way to map multiple functions to the same data. We can then combine that with `nest`ing data and `map`ping `invoke_map` over the nested `data`.

I'll demonstrate with the sample data you give and by defining two functions `f1` and `f2`:

```
f1 <- function(x, y) sum(abs(x - y))
f2 <- function(x, y) sum((x - y)^2)

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(an_id, iTime)  %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(tmp = map(data, ~invoke_map_dfc(
      list(f1 = f1, f2 = f2), 
      x = .x$actual, y = .x$predicted))) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest()
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#  an_id iTime    f1     f2
#  <fct> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 G         1 0.144 0.0196
#2 J         1 1.11  1.23
#3 J         2 0.381 0.0718
#4 G         2 0.01  0.0001
```

Explanation: We group observations by `an_id` and `iTime`, then `nest` the remaining data and use `invoke_map_dfc` inside `map` to apply `f1` and `f2` to `data` and store the result in columns of a nested `tibble`. The last step is removing the `data` column and un-nesting the summary stats.

---

### Update

To reproduce your expected output

```
library(Metrics)
df %>%
  group_by(an_id, iTime)  %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(tmp = map(data, ~invoke_map_dfc(
      list(vmae = mae, rae = rae, vrmse = rmse),
      actual = .x$actual, predicted = .x$predicted))) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest()
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  an_id iTime  vmae   rae  vrmse
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 G         1 0.072 0.253 0.0990
#2 J         1 0.556 0.558 0.785
#3 J         2 0.190 1.44  0.190
#4 G         2 0.038 0.233 0.0472
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "an_id iTime  actual predicted
G 1 1.28     1.14
J           1    2.72        1.61
J           2    0.664       0.475
J        2 0.927    0.737
G        1 0.711    0.715
G        2 1.16     1.15
J        2 0.727    0.725", header = T)
```